# Invoking operation through JMX gives NoAccessRuntimeException

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi, jmx

I am remotely invoking an operation in WebLogic through JMX, I am sending user and password and I have set in Server policies to access JMX operations with the user , but I receive an

`Error creating bean with name 'httpJmxConnector': 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is weblogic.management.NoAccessRuntimeException: Access not allowed for subject: principals=[], on Resource weblogic.management.configuration.AppDeploymentMBean Operation: invoke , Target: lookupSubDeployment`

This is my code: what I do miss?

```
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://theServerAddress:1004/jmxrmi");

    // set JMX Server credentials
    HashMap environment = new HashMap();
    String[]  credentials = new String[] {"theUserName", "thePassword"};
    environment.put (JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS, credentials);

    // connect and get connection to Server
    JMXConnector c = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, environment);
    MBeanServerConnection mbsc = c.getMBeanServerConnection();

    //  Create object name
    ObjectName serviceConfigName = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=deployedApplication-ear,Type=AppDeployment");

    //  Invoke operation
    mbsc.invoke(serviceConfigName, "lookupSubDeployment", null, null);

    c.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below URL to create User properly

http://weblogic-wonders.com/weblogic/2010/11/30/mbean-authorization-and-creating-jmx-policies/

1. Log in to the WebLogic Admin Console.
2. Navigate to Security Realms.
3. Select the name of the realm that you want to control access to MBeans (e.g., myrealm)
4. Navigate to Configurations > General.
5. Check the box for Use Authorization Providers to Protect JMX Access.
6. Restart all managed servers, including the AdminServer.
7. Log back in to the WebLogic Admin Console.
8. Navigate to Roles and Policies > Realm Policies.
9. Click on the link JMX Policy Editor.
10. Select the radio button GLOBAL SCOPE then click Next.
11. Select the radio button ALL MBEAN TYPES then click Next.
12. Select Operations: Permission to Invoke then click Create Policy.
13. Click on Add Condition.
14. Click on Next.
15. Add Admin and Monitor roles in the Role Argument Name field.
16. Click Finish then Save.
17. Logout and log back in and try again.

Comment: Already done: the problem is that this code is not setting the Principal: the exception says : Access not allowed for subject: principals=[] (soprincipal is list is empty)

Comment: Delete already created user and recreate new one with all required role.

Comment: Again.. I made everything, aI am using credentials of Admin and also added Anonymous too and sert a rule: "Allow access to everyone "

Comment: The problem is that I don't pass the credentials with this code: for that motive the exception contains an empty list of credentials